# git diff to see changes from another branch to my working copy

Tags: git

I can compare the uncommitted changes from my working copy with the tip of another branch using:

```
git diff BRANCH
```

How do I reverse this, to see the diff in the other direction, from the tip of another branch to my working copy?

I can compare commits in both directions using:

```
git diff BRANCH HEAD
git diff HEAD BRANCH
```

But those compare **committed** changes in the current branch against another branch. I'm wanting to compare my **uncommitted** changes.

I find this helpful when back-porting changes from a newer branch to an older branch.

Comment: Curious why the down votes... I would rewrite the question if I knew why it was voted down.  I couldn't find it already on StackOverflow, so it's a question I had to solve by reading the docs...

Comment: My guess would be because it is simply a matter of RTFM and experimenting a bit. You have to ask yourself, "Does it look like I value other people's time enough to try to figure it out myself first, or does it look like I do not care about others and am happy to do no work myself and let others spend their time looking at my problem?" (Note that I say "look like" because I do not know what you've done or think.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man git diff` see the -R option, which swaps the inputs.

So to diff from BRANCH to the working copy, instead of from the working copy to BRANCH, use:

```
git diff -R BRANCH
```

Answer (score 1):

`git diff BRANCH` is a short form for `git diff BRANCH HEAD`. Just reverse the parameters and there you go.

Comment: `git diff BRANCH` and `git diff BRANCH HEAD` differ when there are uncommitted changes in the working copy.  I want to compare my working copy with another branch, before committing changes.